# Get Time of Activity Transition Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, oncreate

Is there any way to get the time when an activity changes from a to b

Activity A

{

Intent i = new Intent(A.this,B.class);

startActivity(i);

}

In my app there is a delay when opening an activity. I made some changes and now i want to check the time of activity transition.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use System.nanoTime() as this gives you better precision and accuracy than Calendar or System.currentTimeMillis() and store it in preferences or simply log in Logcat.
2. Alternatively, use Debug.threadCpuTimeNanos() but make sure you measure time passed in the same thread as this will not give you reliable estimation if you attempt to do it in multithreaded environment. In your case you make the measurements on the UI Thread so this method will work for you as well. 
   Be aware, however, that this method focuses on the time execution, for example:

   ```
   long startTime = Debug.threadCpuTimeNanos();

   try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
   } catch (InterruptedException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
   }
   long duration = Debug.threadCpuTimeNanos() - startTime;                  

   Log.i(TAG, "Duration: " + duration + " nanoseconds");
   ```

Depending on the device the logcat prints something around 80 000 000 nanoseconds ~ 80 microseconds.

3. The other methods that allow you to measure time are: SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis(), SystemClock.elapsedRealTime(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis(). 
   Before you use it, be aware what is measured by these methods. [Android Developers docs come with explanation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html).

Comment: Thanks, Short and sweet.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd:MMMM:yyyy HH:mm:ss a");
String strDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
```

to get current time/date

- place it after `startActivity(i);` to get the time when activity should start.
- place it inside your Activity B his `onCreate()` to see when activity is actually getting created.

**edit** 
to show, you can just LOG the `strDate`

Hope this helps ;)